# File upload to sftp server not working

Tags: windows, sftp, windows-server-2016

[image: error]
I have two servers in same network. I can connect a sFTP server from both these server. But cannot upload files with size more than 1KB from Server A, but from B everything is working fine. I checked Firewall policy and also antivirus setting everything is same on both the servers.

Tried with winscp, putty etc.. everywhere same issue I'm getting.
Not getting what's wrong.
The environment is Windows server 2016.. please help

Please [sftp1[][sftp2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82lBL.jpg)

Comment: What error do you get with PuTTY? (actually you cannot transfer a file with PuTTY) - What other software did you try?

Comment: Ialso tried with WinSCP and filezilla

Comment: Again, what error do you get?

Comment: Error screenshot added

Comment: Got the solution.. it was different winscp versions, which were conflicting. My application was using winscp 5.15.1 portable and for checking connectivity I have installed winscp 5.15.5. When both wincp was running at the same time it was blocking the file upload, until the server is restarted. I uninstalled the winscp 5.15.5, and after server restart, it is working fine.